# Not working $(this).removeAttr('123').attr('456','');

Tags: jquery, html, attr

Is there anyone who can solve this? Is about: attr(123,'');

> For example a attr: 123="" to 456=""

Works:

```js
/* Works */ 
$('product[123s0s0]').removeAttr('123s0s0').attr('abc123','');
$('product[abc123]').css({'background-color':'#cfc'});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><product 123s0s0 style="background-color: #ccc">123s0s0 to abc123: Works</product></p>
<p><product 456s0s0 style="background-color: #ccc">456s0s0 to 456s0s1: Not</product></p>
```

Not:

```
$('product[456s0s0]').removeAttr('456s0s0').attr('456s0s1','');
$('product[456s0s1]').css({'background-color':'#cfc'});
```

Comment: The HTML parser (at least in Chrome) seems rather forgiving, and will accept the invalid attribute names. But then trying to add a new invalid attiribute through script will cause this error (again in Chrome) **`Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '456s0s1' is not a valid attribute name`**.

Comment: Unfortunately that seems to be the problem. :-( Thanks tho.

Answer (score 1):

It's because those attributes and the `<product />` tag itself are non-standard. The fact either of them works at all is pretty much luck.

I would suggest using standard HTML tags, unless you really want to write your own doctype, along with `data` attributes to store your custom metadata. Try this:

```js
$('span[data-123s0s0]').removeAttr('data-123s0s0').attr('data-abc123','');
$('span[data-abc123]').addClass('foo');

$('span[data-456s0s0]').removeAttr('data-456s0s0').attr('data-456s0s1','');
$('span[data-456s0s1]').addClass('foo');
```

```css
span { background-color: #CCC; }
.foo { background-color: #CFC; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><span data-123s0s0>123s0s0 to abc123: Works</span></p>
<p><span data-456s0s0>456s0s0 to 456s0s1: Works</span></p>
```

Comment: It is more difficult than just a background, that was an example. At onclick, the part command changes, which sends information to SQL and then the attr changes. These types of attr are used in many others. So order is difficult to change. Is this possible?

Comment: The logic that's performed is not relevant to the changes above, they will still work when done this way.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Attribute name can't be start with digits. So first character of the attribute must be a string or underscore.

```
$('product[456s0s0]').removeAttr('456s0s0').attr('f456s0s1','');
$('product[456s0s1]').css({'background-color':'#cfc'});
```

Comment: I tried on chrome and it gives DOM error in console.

Answer (score 0):

It seems attr can't start width a number.

> The HTML parser (at least in Chrome) seems rather forgiving, and will accept the invalid attribute names. But then trying to add a new invalid attiribute through script will cause this error (again in Chrome) **Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '456s0s1' is not a valid attribute name.** – *Peter B*